# multiple clients playing video on jw player at same time

Tags: jwplayer, wowza

I want to stream videos from multiple android devices(clients) to Jw player using Wowza server. How can I achieve that?  I can stream only one video at a time right now. Not getting any help on how to stream multiple video simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think the player itself has this sort of a limitation, that would be entirely on your server's end.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to have is a so called application defined in your Wowza Streaming Servier, which I guess you already have. This application, let's suppose it's called `live` can receive multiple live streams from different sources, e.g. GoCoders. Each source can publish a stream with custom name into your application, and then you can choose which one to play in your JW Player's setup, by specifying the stream name in the URL.

(It's not clear to me if you wanted to play multiple videos simultaneously in the same JW Player instance, in a picture-in-picture style.)